# Yii Core Library in Cross/Different Hosting Server

Tags: php, yii

I use shared hosting and didn't want to install core library of Yii in each of my every shared hosting account.
Because of that, i want to put the library in one shared hosting and use it in all of my account shared hosting.
Is this can be done or what will be the consequence because of this?

example code of `index.php` in Yii will be:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii='http://gusdecool.com/Script/Yii/1.1.13/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a shared hosting, you probably can't do that. I mean, if your are trying to use the same yii framework folder for multiple domains, it probably will raise an error (open base dir or similar) because you cant acces from the account from domainA to the account of the domainB.

I manage dedicated servers, i put the framework directory on the php include path and I'm done.

You may ask to your hosting provider if they can do that.

**Edit**
I've just seen:

```
$yii='http://gusdecool.com/Script/Yii/1.1.13/yii.php';
```

You can't do that. If you access to that file vía http it will return you html code, no the php code itself. You have to do

```
$yii = '/whatever/path/gusdecool.com/Yii/1.1.13/yii.php';
```

but, as i said before, it has to be in your include path

Comment: Thank you, i will ask my hosting provider to provide include library :)

Comment: Good luck. The best thing you can do is talk with your hosting provider. There's a lot of ways to solve your issue, but if you don't have access to the server... you are out of luck. Talk to them ^^